# Laravel Dataset Parsing Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I need to parse this dataset I already but I tried several ways but it doesnt work.

```
{"id":2,"area_id":"1","payment_term_id":"1","payment_type_id":"1","trade_channel_id":"1","salesman_id":1,"customer_name":"xxx","contact_number":"1231212","fax_number":"1231232","home_address":"asd","delivery_address":"dasd","email_address":"test@edit.com","created_by":"4","updated_by":"4","is_active":"1","created_at":"2017-10-17 06:02:59","updated_at":"2017-10-17 06:13:22"}
```

I tried this one  but This error says that

(1/1) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

```
$details = $request->get('details');
return $details->id;
```

I also tried this one

```
$details = $request->get('details');
return $details['id'];
```

(1/1) ErrorException
Illegal string offset 'id'

I'm using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data comes from the request, it a JSON and not a collection or an object. So, you need to do something like this:

```
return json_decode($request->details)->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the JSON payload in your controller, use:

```
$details = json_decode($request->details)->id);
dd($details);
```

instead of

```
$details = $request->get('details');
return $details['id'];
```

Comment: You'll get `Trying to get property of non-object` with this code. You need to decode it first and then get ID.

Answer (score 1):

To use as array like `$details['id']` try this :

```
$details = json_decode($request->details, true);
echo $details['id'];
```